# How can I formed as below permutation problem

Tags: probability, permutations

Hi I am writing a program and i encouraged the below permutation problem and need your help.

There are 4 boxes:

- 3 of them have 2 balls
- The one box has 1 balls.

The question is what is the possibility when I process below rules.

1. You must choice 3 ball
2. The your choiced balls can not be in the same box.

For example;
Box1's ball color is green,
Box2's ball color is blue
Box3's ball color is black
Box4's ball color is pink

True choices:

```
Green + Blue + Black
Green + Black + Pink
```

Wrong choices

```
Green + Green + Black //there are same color
```

The boxes count can change, and the boxes can have more than 2 balls. So how can i get formula of this question.

Comment: Please clarify the mechanism by which I may select balls. For example, in your illustration, if I pick three boxes at random without replacement and then one ball from each box, I guess I will have done it correctly. Then it's just ${4 \choose 3}$, but that seems absurdly simple. Do I pick boxes with replacement? Just sample 3 balls without regard to boxes?  Also, your True and False choices show only two balls being chosen, not three. Very unclear to me.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo I edited the examples, sorry.  Actualy i guess you are right and I have already tried to solve the problem using combination like your offer but that formule did not solve it. let me give you more information about what i am doing. I am trying to figure out betting odds coupon. You can see a screenshot of bet odds. https://gyazo.com/600e97b38f182169318d80fbb5c9ef06 You can play in this situtation 2 system game (2 odds),and 3 system game(3 odds). For example your 2 system game does not include more than 1 odds in the same row. So you can't play 2.17 and 3.47 in same game.

Comment: You can play for 2 system games 2.17 + 1.73 and 2.17 + 3.47 and + 2.17 + 5.72 and 3.47 + 1.73 and ... 2.04 + 1.25 For 3 system games 2.17 + 1.73 + 2.04 and 2.17 + 1.73 + 3.42 etc. So the question is that hom many combination occurs

Comment: How about organizing some of what's in your last two comments and editing it into your question. Best way to get people interested. (Not an expert at combinatorics, but will look at it.)